# CSS keyframes not applying last rule set at the 100% mark

Tags: css, css-animations

The following CSS animation is not applying the last rule : `display: none;`. What am I doing wrong ?

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.to-hide').addClass('hidden');
}, 2000);
```

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
      0%   { opacity: 1; }
      99%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { display: none; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fade-out {
      0%   { opacity: 1; }
      99%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { display: none; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes fade-out {
      0%   { opacity: 1; }
      99%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { display: none; }
    }
    @keyframes fade-out {
      0%   { opacity: 1; }
      99%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { display: none; }
    }
    
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: blue;
}

.to-hide {
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          -moz-animation-name:    fade-out;
          -o-animation-name:      fade-out;
          animation-name:         fade-out;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
          -moz-animation-duration:    0.8s;
          -o-animation-duration:      0.8s;
          animation-duration:         0.8s;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          -moz-animation-timing-function:    ease-in-out;
          -o-animation-timing-function:      ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function:         ease-in-out;
          -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -moz-animation-fill-mode:    forwards;
          -o-animation-fill-mode:      forwards;
          animation-fill-mode:         forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `display` can not be animated, nor can it be transitioned.

Comment: I know, I don't want to animate it or transition it, I want to apply `display: none;` as soon as the animation is done, by only using CSS

Comment: Okay let me reword it: The `display` property cannot be part of an animation or transition.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use `display: none` for transitions or animations you could simulate it by animating the height of the div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   clear: both;
   background-color: blue;
}

.to-hide {
   background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
   animation: fade-out 0.8s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   99% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     height: 0;
   }
}
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.to-hide').addClass('hidden');
}, 2000);
```

```css
div {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   clear: both;
   background-color: blue;
 }
 
 .to-hide {
   background-color: red;
 }
 
 .hidden {
   animation: fade-out 0.8s ease-in-out forwards;
 }
 
 @keyframes fade-out {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   99% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     height: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div class="to-hide"></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your animation is starting at 0% getting to 100% and starting all over again. If you want it to run just once as opposed to infitely which is what it looks like it is doing, try adding:

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

If that does not work I also suspect that you cannot add `display:none;` to css3 keyframes, instead add opacity: 0; at 100%.

Comment: it's not running infinitely, `display: none;` is simply being ignored by keyframes which sucks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to set `display: none` at the end of the animation to remove the items from the display list and free the space they are taking up.

Hence you can't set display in a keyframe animation you could use the `animationend` event that every css animation triggers at the end and set `display: none`in the event handler.

example (the js snippet):

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.to-hide').addClass('hidden');
}, 2000);

document.body.addEventListener('animationend', removeElement);
document.body.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', removeElement);

function removeElement(event) {
  if (event.animationName === 'fade-out') {
    console.log(event.target);
    $(event.target).addClass('display-none');
  }
}
```

supposing you have an extra css class selector:

```
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

But yes it adds javascript and is not css only.

You might as well play around with the `scale` property for a css only workaround.
See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991523/hide-div-after-css3-animation).