# How to make a div display:none after a css animation that makes it fade away?

Tags: html, css, animation, display

I have an epilepsy warning appear on my website before fading away to reveal the nightmare it is. Sadly, after it fades away, you can't click on any of the input fields due to the div not being display:none after the animation. Here is the css3 animation code:

```
#warning{
    background-color:Silver;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-animation: warning 6s ease-out forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes warning {
    0%  {background-color:Silver;opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    80% {opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    100%{opacity:0;z-index:0;}
}
```

So how can I make it possible to click on the input fields?

Comment: what `div` ? can you post the html code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide div after CSS3 Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991523/hide-div-after-css3-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `pointer-events:none;` to the `#warning{`. They can still click on things (even when they can't see them) with the overlay up.

Here's an example:

```css
#warning{
    background-color:Silver;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events: none; /* The new addition */
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-animation: warning 6s ease-out forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes warning {
    0%  {background-color:Silver;opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    80% {opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    100%{opacity:0;z-index:0;}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('clicked')">Click Me!!!</button>
<div id="warning">Warning!!!!!!</div>
```

### Edit

Or, you could set the `z-index` to -1 for the animation.

```css
#warning{
    background-color:Silver;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-animation: warning 6s ease-out forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes warning {
    0%  {background-color:Silver;opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    80% {opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    100%{opacity:0;z-index:-1;} /* Change Made */
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('clicked')">Click Me!!!</button>
<div id="warning">Warning!!!!!!</div>
```

It all depends on what you want to do obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javaScript `animationend` event. (IE10 ++)

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('warning');

cont.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  console.log('animation ended, lets change display');
  cont.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#warning{
    background-color:Silver;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-animation: warning 6s ease-out forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes warning {
    0%  {background-color:Silver;opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    80% {opacity:1;z-index:2;}
    100%{opacity:0;z-index:0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="warning"></div>
```